# The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk' specified could not be found. in Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.5

Tags: .net, visual-studio

Since Visual Studio 2022 updated from version 17.4 to 17.5, I couldn't load my project. and get the error "The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk' specified could not be found." But if the project was opened in version 17.4, the project was loaded successfully.

Anyone have a solution for this case ?

I have trying to open my net6 project in visual studio community 2022 version 17.5 but couldn't loaded. so what should i do for this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Possibly changing some attributes in a vbproj file (or possibly equivalent change in other types of project files), I had similar issues...
I changed

$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)

To

$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)

And than all works!

Comment: In the simplified Microsoft.Net.SDK type project, such values do not exist.  Those only exist in old-school *.??proj files.   Since the issue is that old-school project files load, while SDK-style projects do not, this suggestion is unlikely to fix the OP's issue.  It did not help me, while looking to solve the same problem (upgrading from 17.3 to 17.5 broke all my SDK-based projects).